# The false value is not returned from the function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I apologize if this question stupid, but I'm trying to return `True` if the current item is equal to the next item and return `False` if not :

```
def isSame(array):
    for index, number in enumerate(array):
        if number == array[index + 1]:
            return True
    return False

print(isSame([1, 3, 2, 6, 5, 3, 2]))
```

The True value return if I call the function like this : `isSame([1, 3, 2, 6, 5, 3, 3])`

But when I call it like this : `isSame([1, 3, 2, 6, 5, 3, 2])` the function does not return any value.

Comment: Try `if number == array[index - 1]:`

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast thank you so much, could you please explain to me, why `index - 1` and not `index + 1`

Comment: This is because your current program checks the last value against the next value, not the previous value. It'll show an error if you use `index + 1` since the last value in the array doesn't have anything to check against. This is why you get the error `list index out of range`.

Answer (score 0):

Zips may be useful in this scenario, this basically takes the list of all values starting at one and then the list of all values starting at zero, combines them into one variable and then iterates over the list of those pairs and checks if they are equal and returns true if they are and false if not, and because this is a listcomp, it returns it as a list.
`z=lambda g:[x[0]==x[1] for x in zip(g[0:],g[1:])]`

Answer (score 0):

it does not return false because the script is stopped by error `IndexError: list index out of range`, add check `if index + 1 > len(array) - 1:`

```
def isSame(array):
    for index, number in enumerate(array):
        if index + 1 > len(array) - 1:
            print("IndexError: list index out of range")
            continue
        if number == array[index + 1]:
            return True
    return False


print(isSame([1, 3, 2, 6, 5, 3, 2]))
```